# Transaction Data

Tags: r, duplicates, set-intersection

I've got a dataset that contains purchase data and I'm stuck trying to figure something out. Before jumping into it, here is what my data looks like:

```
> df.f[df.f$CUST_ID == badIDs[1], c(1, 20, 4, 11, 13)]

CUST_ID CI2_TRANS_DT HR_SID NDS_AMT PROD_NUM
   1    2013-12-14     10    0.00    a5g4324
   1    2013-12-14     10    0.00    k4jn42k
   1    2013-12-14     10    0.00  f3ft52f3
   1    2013-12-14     10    0.00    f454fn
   1    2013-12-14     10    0.00    l2k41m
   1    2013-12-14     10    2.25  nb24b2x3
   1    2013-12-14     10    0.00    k1s4m6
   1    2013-12-14     10    0.00    1z34fl
   1    2013-12-14     10    0.95  f3ft52f3
   1    2013-12-17      6    4.45    v0d45j
   1    2013-12-17      6    0.00    a5g4324
   1    2013-12-17      6    4.75  g6b673va
   1    2013-12-17      6    0.00    f454fn
   1    2013-12-19      7   -4.75  bh431d11
   1    2013-12-20      6    4.75  bh431d11
   2    2013-12-14      6    4.75  g6b673va
   2    2013-12-15      6    3.75  nb24b2x3
   2    2013-12-15      6   -3.75  nb24b2x3
   2    2013-12-16      6    5.90  bh431d11
```

The above variables are the Customer ID Number, the Date of the Transaction, the Hour of the Day, the Sale Amount, and the Product Number, in that order. The problem I'm having is with the negative values of NDS_AMT. If the value is negative, I need to check to see if there is a corresponding purchase and if there is, then the negative value can stay in. If there is no corresponding purchase, then I need to remove that record from my data. As an example, the second to last record would need to be removed since it's negative and there is no corresponding purchase for that same day. The same product is purchased the next day, but since they're on two different visits they can't be counted as corresponding purchases.

I've tried thinking about how to do this and have considered embedded apply functions, intersect functions or duplicate functions, but regardless of the function I can't grasp how to write the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Per Henrik's request, I have added four new rows to the data for a new customer that has a negative NDS_AMT where the record *should* stay in the data. The conditions for a "corresponding purchase" are that the CUST_ID, CI2_TRANS_DT, HR_SID and PROD_NUM values must all match those of the records where the NDS_AMT is less than 0.

Comment: I think you need to provide an **minimal** example with an instance where "negative value can stay in" and when they should be removed. You need to clarify how to tell if "there is no corresponding purchase for that same day". Cheers.

Comment: I made some edits to satisfy your requests; please let me know if more data is needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So here is the solution I've come up with. Obviously feel free to suggest tweaks as you see fit.

```
refundRecords <- df.f[df.f$NDS_AMT < 0, ]
refundRecords$NDS_AMT <- refundRecords$NDS_AMT * -1
dups <- apply(refundRecords, 1, function(x) apply(df.f[df.f$CUST_ID == x[1], ], 1, function(y) sum(x %in% y)))
id2check <- sapply(dups, function(x) any(x == 5))
badIDs <- unique(df.f$CUST_ID[rownames(df.f) %in% names(id2check[!id2check])])
df.f <- df.f[df.f$NDS_AMT >= 0 | !(df.f$CUST_ID %in% badIDs), ]
```